# Django: Can I use a subprocess w/ docker-compose inside a custom command?

Tags: python, django, docker, docker-compose, django-commands

I created a custom command in django and I want to use a docker-compose command in it. I use a subprocess as follow:

```
class Command(BaseCommand):

def handle(self, *args, **options):
    data = open_file()
    os.environ['DATA'] = data
    command_name = ["docker-compose ", "-f", "docker-compose.admin.yml", "up"]
    popen = subprocess.Popen(command_name, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
                             universal_newlines=True)
    return popen
```

when I do it I get a FileNotFoundError:

> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'docker-compose ': 'docker-compose

Is it even possible to use docker-compose inside of a command ?
It feels like I am missing something.

Thank you !

Comment: Probably need `shell=true`?

Comment: There's an extra space after `docker-compose `.  (Do _not_ use `shell=True`: it's fairly easy to introduce security issues that would make it possible to root the whole host.)

Answer (score 1):

I see 2 possible things.

1. Your docker compose should run in background, so, you should add `-d` option at the end of the command: `docker-compose -f docker-compose.admin.yml up -d`
2. Best practice is start docker compose in background and you can take output with popen executing `docker-compose -f docker-compose.admin.yml logs`

You can also run docker-compose services and get interactive output, defining `stdin_open: true` in your yml file.

3. You could check if your current directory is where docker-compose.admin.yml exists, printing `os.getcwd()` and comparing it to docker-compose.admin.yml path.